# How to get Audio level in Kurento to show on UI

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, webrtc, kurento

I am developing multiparty conferencing in nodejs using kurento (kurento-utils-js on client side and kurento-client package on server side)

When someone speaks (either local or on remote stream), I want to show the audio level on user interface (UI) to just show that he/she is speaking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hark` API provided by `kurentoUtils`. Tweak the threshold between [-100, 0] to see which values works best for you. -50 works for me.

```
const speechEvent =kurentoUtils.WebRtcPeer.hark(stream, { threshold: -50 });
speechEvent.on('speaking', () => {
 /* do something on the UI */
});
speechEvent.on('stopped_speaking', () => {
  /* do something on the UI */
});
```